# Add a youtube video in the template file using url

Tags: 7, files

I've tried using this code `<?php print theme('video_embed_field_embed_code', array('url' => $video['http://www.youtube.com/embed/Zz1HPLtecOg'])); ?>` but it only displays the url and doesnt show the video. How can I fix this?

Comment: are you trying to print a field, or hardcode the display of the video?

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php print render($content['field_video_url]']);?>
```

try this